# move margin of pages for bookbinding

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, book-design

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{indentfirst}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

  \pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{14pt}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ #1}{}}

  \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
  \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}

  \begin{document}
```

I'd like to move the left margin for odd pages a bit more to the right, vice versa for even pages, right margin moved a bit more the left. I need more space in the sides of the bookbinding, with this configuration is centered so the binding takes space and the result is visually asymmetrical and difficult to browse.
How should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) package. In my experience it is by far the easiest way to precisely control all of the page dimensions, including margins.

Comment: Either the `geometry` package, as Andrew already wrote or the usage of `scrbook` instead of `book` which takes care of the binding correction

Answer (score 1):

The lengths `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` need to be augmented/decremented.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{indentfirst}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

  \pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{14pt}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ #1}{}}

  \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
  \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{1cm}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1cm}
  \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much!! I was putting \oddsidemargin and the other with \pagestyle